# if_else, ifelse and case_when returning different results

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying conditional statement for groups using dplyr.
I don't know if this is normal behavior and i'm just reaching dplyr's limits there, if it is a bug or if it's just confusing, but all of the following conditional statements return different things :

```r
library(dplyr)

data("cms_patient_care", package = "tidyr")

cms_patient_care2 <- cms_patient_care %>%
  arrange(ccn, measure_abbr)%>%
  group_by(ccn, measure_abbr)%>%
  mutate(
    score2 = ifelse(n()>1, score, 0), 
    score3 = if_else(n()>1, score, 0),
    score4 = case_when(
      n()>1             ~ score,
      TRUE              ~ 0)
    )%>%
  ungroup()
cms_patient_care2 %>% head(10)
```

- ifelse returns the same value (the first of the group) for every observation in the group if the condition is verified ;
- if_else doesn't work because it reuses the vector of the condition and here size doesn't match ;
- case_when actually returns what would seem logical : the initial value if condition is verified

I personally want the case_when result.
Should I use if_else differently ? Or is case_when the only way to obtain what I want ?

Comment: `if_else()` (and `ifelse()`) are explicitly for *vectorised conditions*. If you only have a single condition (as here), you should use regular `if…else`. The fact that `if_else()` doesn’t work here (whereas `ifelse()` silently returns a bogus result) is the very reason why `if_else()` exists. The fact that `case_when()` silently works here even though it is also vectorised is arguably unfortunate; it should probably fail, same as `if_else()`.

Comment: Are you sure you want just n()? Try creating the variable first with mutate: `mutate(n = n())`, it just returns 2 for every group, as there are two rows inside every group. Maybe you intended to use `mutate(n = 1:n())`, which numbers the rows of each group (1, 2), so that you can target the row with the first observation in each group in the ifelse/case_when?

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks! I guess i never fully understood that, especially with `case_when` working. Can you post an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera that was just the easiest reprex i could think of, thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) is explicitly designed to be used with a vector `condition` argument; the length of that argument determines the output:

> ```r
> if_else(condition, true, false, missing = NULL, ..., ptype = NULL, size = NULL)
> ```
>
> […]
> Both `true` and `false` will be recycled to the size of `condition`.

In your case, the condition has (and is intended to have) length 1. You don’t need a vectorised function for that; instead, regular `if…else…` does exactly what you want:

```r
cms_patient_care2 <- cms_patient_care %>%
  arrange(ccn, measure_abbr) %>%
  group_by(ccn, measure_abbr) %>%
  mutate(
    score2 = if (n() > 1) score else 0,
    score3 = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ score,
      TRUE    ~ 0
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
cms_patient_care2 %>% head(10)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
   ccn    facility_name   measure_abbr      score type        score2 score3
   <chr>  <chr>           <chr>             <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE beliefs_addressed 202   denominator  202    202
 2 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE beliefs_addressed 100   observed     100    100
 3 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE composite_process 202   denominator  202    202
 4 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE composite_process  88.1 observed      88.1   88.1
 5 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspena_treatment 110   denominator  110    110
 6 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspena_treatment  99.1 observed      99.1   99.1
 7 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspnea_screening 202   denominator  202    202
 8 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspnea_screening 100   observed     100    100
 9 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE opioid_bowel       61   denominator   61     61
10 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE opioid_bowel      100   observed     100    100
```

The fact that `ifelse()` silently returns a bogus result was there precise reason for which `if_else()` exists: to prevent icky situations where usage errors result in incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try to use `val` and use it so all the three functions return the same result

```r
cms_patient_care2 <- cms_patient_care %>%
  arrange(ccn, measure_abbr)%>%
  group_by(ccn, measure_abbr)%>%
  mutate(val=n()>1,
    score2 = ifelse(val, score, 0), 
    score3 = if_else(val, score, 0),
    score4 = case_when(
      val            ~ score,
      TRUE              ~ 0)
  )%>%
  ungroup()
cms_patient_care2 %>% head(10)
```

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   ccn    facility_name   measure_abbr   score type  val   score2 score3
   <chr>  <chr>           <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE beliefs_addre… 202   deno… TRUE   202    202  
 2 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE beliefs_addre… 100   obse… TRUE   100    100  
 3 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE composite_pro… 202   deno… TRUE   202    202  
 4 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE composite_pro…  88.1 obse… TRUE    88.1   88.1
 5 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspena_treat… 110   deno… TRUE   110    110  
 6 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspena_treat…  99.1 obse… TRUE    99.1   99.1
 7 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspnea_scree… 202   deno… TRUE   202    202  
 8 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE dyspnea_scree… 100   obse… TRUE   100    100  
 9 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE opioid_bowel    61   deno… TRUE    61     61  
10 011500 BAPTIST HOSPICE opioid_bowel   100   obse… TRUE   100    100  
# ℹ 1 more variable: score4 <dbl>
```